# How can I stream an audio recording realtime in ionic to Firebase?

Tags: typescript, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, media

I'm trying to implement realtime speech to text recognition with Google API service using Ionic as a frontend. I am not able to find a library that can record from Ionic and stream the recording in realtime to be stored in the google bucket storage. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you need to use any special library/plugin to do this, you can simply use Web Technologies to achieve this by using [MediaDevices API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices) to [getUserMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) for getting Audio stream from device microphone and using [Web Speech API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API/Using_the_Web_Speech_API) for speech recognition, and use [WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) to transmit real-time audio stream to Google Speech-to-Text API and receive real-time response back.

For further reading, check the following resources:

[Delivering a Smooth Cross-Browser Speech to Text Experience](https://medium.com/ideas-at-igenius/delivering-a-smooth-cross-browser-speech-to-text-experience-b1e1f1f194a2)

[Speaking with a Webpage - Streaming speech transcripts](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/speaking-with-a-webpage/index.html?index=..%2F..index#7)

Comment: Thanks Sherif.  Is this method supported on a cross-platform mobile app development environment such as Ionic?  Arabic is not one of the languages in this demo  https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html  so does it support Arabic

Comment: Yes, It can be used in Ionic as Ionic apps are rendered in a Webview in mobile platforms, but make sure to check Safari Webview & Android Webview compatibility with browser APIs you're going to use to make sure it suits your target clients. You can find compatibility details in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org) or [Caniuse](https://caniuse.com).

Regarding language support, Yes, Arabic is supported, you can test it yourself by editing page inline script and adding  `['Arabic', ['ar']],` to the langs array and rerun the whole script to reinitialize everything to see 'Arabic' option in menu

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to use the React Native framework. You can checkout [Media plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/media) from the Ionic framework that can be used to record the audio files. Here is an [example](https://www.djamware.com/post/5a18411b80aca75eadc12d6d/record-and-play-sound-in-ionic-3-angular-5-cordova-mobile-app)(which is developed using angular, but you can understand the underlying concept). Also for using Firebase to stream in real-time, check out the firebase [plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase).

There are Streaming media [plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/streaming-media), which can also be used in your case.
For more reference, I would suggest using the official documentation and look into this [blog post](https://medium.com/enappd/play-spotify-like-music-in-ionic-4-apps-5fea942c31b5)

Comment: Hello thanks for your effort but I have tried all of these I couldn't find a way to upload the audio in a bucket while recording it, I think streaming media plugin only stream from not stream to.